# Why a domain name which was available now appears as created 15 years ago?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois

I chose a name for my website and I wanted to purchase it.
Few days ago I searched it on the Whois search engine and it was listed as available. Now I do it again and I read it has been created on 2001 and updated today: It is no longer available. I guess the owner updated his/her license right now, but I cannot understand why Whois didn't tell me it already had an owner, I mean it seemed I was completely able to purchase it if I wanted.

Why did the name domain appear as available, although it had already been registered?

---

edit->

it also happened with another domain name I was monitoring, I noticed right now.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the website you used originally to check on the domain had an outdated database. Or the domain may have expired from the original owner and was temporarily available when you checked for it. The age of the domain seems suspicious though. My suggestion would be to always buy any domain available that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that you entered different domain names each time, sorry.
Without the domain names themselves, noone can really help you.

Also the "Whois search engine" does not mean anything : each registry TLD has a whois (both port 43 and through their website most of the times) and this is where you should do your queries, or at worst through the registrar you trust with your other domains. You should not use any website offering whois searches.

So we have no idea what you queried for nor how you did it…